# Using scalar variables to refer to an array inside an explicit generator

Tags: raku

I've written a code to calculate the Fibonacci series using array variables inside the explicit generator like this:

```perl
my @fib = [0],[1],-> @a, @b {[|@a Z+ |@b]} ... Inf;
say @fib[^6];
```

This works as expected. But when I use scalar variables inside the same code, it works too:

```perl
my @fib_v2 = [0],[1],-> $a, $b {[|$a Z+ |$b]} ... Inf;
say @fib_v2[^6];
```

Could they be called scalar variables pointing to the arrays? What are they called when they are used in this manner?

Note that I've browsed the online Raku documentation but it's hard to spot that particular information i.e. if arrays can be referred using scalar variables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should say that "the scalar variables are **bound** to the arrays".  Because that is what happens.  You could think of:

```
-> $a, $b { say $a; say $b }("foo", "bar")
```

as:

```
{ my $a := "foo"; my $b := "bar"; say $a; say $b }
```

So, when you bind an array to a scalar, it is still an `Array` object.  And calling methods on it, will just work.  It may just make reading the code more difficult.

Note this is different from **assigning** an array to a scalar.

```
raku -e 'my $a := [1,2,3]; .say for $a'
1
2
3
```

versus:

```
raku -e 'my $a = [1,2,3]; .say for $a'
[1 2 3]
```

The `for` iterating logic sees the container in `$a` and takes that as a sign to *NOT* iterate over it, even though it contains an `Iterable`.

> Note that I've browsed the online Raku documentation but it's hard to spot that particular information i.e. if arrays can be referred using scalar variables.

It basically falls out of correctly grokking the relation between containers and binding.  About 4 years ago, I wrote a blog post about it: https://opensource.com/article/18/8/containers-perl-6 Please pardon the archaic naming  :-)